# Is it possible to get my question reopened from closed status?

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question, duplicate-questions, reopen-closed

I asked the following question:

[How to detect antivirus on Windows Server 2008 in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13732351/how-to-detect-antivirus-on-windows-server-2008-in-c)

but it got flagged as an exact duplicate of

[How to detect antivirus installed on windows 2003 server and 2008 server 2003 server R2and 2008 server R2 using WMI or other then WMI in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396757/how-to-detect-antivirus-installed-on-windows-2003-server-and-2008-server-2003-se)

The duplicate in question is asking for an answer specific to C++, whereas my question is specific to C#. While the two questions are similar, they revolve around different programming languages, so the answers are going to be different.

I feel that the they are certainly different enough to warrant having separate questions.  Is it possible to have a closed question be reopened?

Answer (score 2):

While the concepts certainly may be the same, the implementation most definitely might not be, given the capabilities of different languages/runtimes and therefore not duplicates.

I've reopened the question.

Answer (score 1):

Further to CasperOne's answer and Coming to your question, If it gets 5 votes from people who have 3K+ reputation, it certainly would be re-opened.

Comment: 5 votes from users **or one mod vote** reopens (or closes) a question.